# QtQuick pathCurve curve line on mouse click event

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

Hey posting this question to learn how to curve a line onclick i.e using path-curve i want to curve a line but not hard-coded it occur on mouse click event like if clicked on (400,320) then line at that position Y position will change (let say +75) as in image it is hard-coded but i want curve onclick wherever mouse click event occur it should curve

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my implementation. It's not exactly the shape you want. It seems that you can not get something like your image with `PathCurve` but surely you have much more control over the outcome with ***[PathCubic](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-pathcubic.html)***.

```
        Canvas {
            id: canvas
            width: 640; height: 640
            contextType: "2d"

            Path {
                id: myPath
                startX: 320; startY: 0

                PathCurve { id: curvePoint_top; x: 320; y: curvePoint.y - 80 }
                PathCurve { id: curvePoint; x: 320; y: 320 }
                PathCurve { id: curvePoint_bottom; x: 320; y: curvePoint.y + 80 }
                PathCurve { x: 320; y: 640 }
            }

            onPaint: {
                context.clearRect(0,0,width,height);
                context.strokeStyle = Qt.rgba(.4,.6,.8);
                context.path = myPath;
                context.stroke();
            }

            MouseArea{
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: {
                    curvePoint.x = mouseX;
                    curvePoint.y = mouseY;
                    canvas.requestPaint();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: very nice example!